# How to Use Mappings Generic in Python

Tags: python, generics, python-typing

I want to build an (abstract) Dataset which is generic and just provides the framework for loading files.

The subclasses are then for specific types (here bother the samples and the annotations are of type `np.ndarray`

When I instantiate an object of type `ImageDataset` I get

```
 File "/home/maximilian/darts/tests/test_dataset.py", line 12, in test_simple_loading
    dataset = ImageDataset(dataset_root)
  File "/home/maximilian/darts/darts/datasets.py", line 72, in __init__
    super(ImageDataset, self).__init__(path)
  File "/home/maximilian/darts/darts/datasets.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.__load_data(path)
  File "/home/maximilian/darts/darts/datasets.py", line 48, in __load_data
    self.annotations.update(annotations)
AttributeError: 'ImageDataset' object has no attribute 'annotations'
```

Can anybody tell me please what I am doing wrong here?

```py
from collections import defaultdict

from abc import abstractmethod
from itertools import tee
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Iterator, TypeVar, Tuple, Dict, Mapping
import numpy as np
from cv2 import haveImageReader, imread

Key = str
Annotation = TypeVar('Annotation')
Sample = TypeVar('Sample')
AnnotatedSample = Tuple[Sample, Annotation]


class Dataset(Mapping[Key, AnnotatedSample]):
    def __init__(self, path: Path):
        self.__path = path
        self.__load_data(path)
        self.annotations: Dict[str, Annotation] = defaultdict(lambda: None)
        self.samples: Dict[str, Sample] = defaultdict(lambda: None)

    @abstractmethod
    def _is_sample_file(self, file : Path) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def _is_annotation_file(self, file : Path) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def _load_annotation(self, file: Path) -> Annotation:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def _load_sample(self, file: Path) -> Sample:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __load_data(self, path: Path):
        files = filter(lambda file: not file.is_dir(), path.glob('*'))
        it1, it2 = tee(files)
        annotations_files = filter(lambda file: self._is_annotation_file(file), it1)
        sample_files = filter(lambda file: self._is_sample_file(file), it2)

        annotations = map(lambda file: (file.stem, self._load_annotation(file)), annotations_files)
        samples = map(lambda file: (file.stem, self._load_sample(file)), sample_files)

        self.annotations.update(annotations)
        self.samples.update(samples)

        annotation_keys = set(self.annotations)
        samples_keys = set(self.samples)
        annotations_without_sample = annotation_keys.difference(samples_keys)
        if annotations_without_sample:
            raise ValueError(
                f"For each annotation a sample file must be given. Annotation without sample {annotations_without_sample} ")

    def __getitem__(self, k: Key) -> AnnotatedSample:
        return self.samples[k], self.annotations

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.samples)

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[Key]:
        return self.samples.keys()


class ImageDataset(Dataset[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]):
    ANNOTATION_EXTENSIONS = ['.npy']

    def __init__(self, path : Path, transformations = []):
        super(ImageDataset, self).__init__(path)
        self.__transformations = transformations

    def _is_annotation_file(self, file: Path) -> bool:
        return haveImageReader(str(file))

    def _is_sample_file(self, file: Path) -> bool:
        return file.stem in ImageDataset.ANNOTATION_EXTENSIONS

    def _load_annotation(self, file: Path) -> Annotation:
        return np.load(str(file))

    def _load_sample(self, file: Path) -> Sample:
        image = imread(str(file))
        for transform in self.__transformations:
            image = transform(image)
        return image
```

Comment: Try to move `self.__load_data(path)` to the end of `__init__`

Comment: Oh yea, that's it. How embarrassing.

Thanks anyways